# select row from list

Tags: php, html, mysql

Asking help from experts i've been working with this for quite sometime.

here's the logic:

the products already viewed

```
serial | name      | description          
---+-----------+----------------
1      | name1      | desc1
2      | name2      | desc2
3      | name3      | desc3
4      | name4      | desc4
```

I like to have a script where i if i click on the product another file will open and will show the product clicked.

appreciate any help.

Comment: Is it question? or your work?

Comment: Are you asking us to do your work?

Comment: you want help, or want us to write code? Confusion..o.O

Comment: Pass the `productid` in the query string from products list page and on the product summary page, use `$_GET['productid']` to get the requested product and `query` for the particular product and display the results.

Comment: You can put the product name in hyperlink passing the product id in it and adding target="_blank" to the link so that the product description opens up in new window

Comment: $_GET or $_Post, Javascript, id and forms is probably all you need to know to do that.

Comment: This is a question asking for a script to help. not a work either.

I'm trying to create a shopping cart digging deeper knowledge for php and sql.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the product id of the selected product in query string and in second page get this id and fetch the contents from database with this id and show it in that page :)

Comment: can you give me a script for a lighter understanding.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have a list of products shown on the page. The URL needs to be something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM series";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<a href='http://example.com/index.php?pag=products&productid={$row[id]}'>{$row[name]}</a>";
}
```

So basically you pass the product id to a page. $_GET['pag'] is something I used to know what I should load (ie what file).

Then on the product page, you get the product id, and show the information however you want.

```
$productId = intval($_GET['product_id']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM series WHERE id = {$productId} LIMIT 1"; // we'll get a single product anyway

// show the HTML you want from here on
```

Comment: Thanks a big help! Can you please include echoing the name?